# Accessing event from another class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

I'm trying to switch between two frames in my main program.
The trigger to switching to the second frame from the first one, is one condition to be met and one button to be pressed in the first frame.

This is one example that I've tried so far, but the `actionPerformed` method only accepts a parameterized local variable `e` for `ActionEvent` so I'm unable to use this `.getEvent()` method in my main which access an empty `ActionEvent` field.

Do you have any idea on how i could proceed to achieve this?

- `pb` = progress bar
- `next` = button

---

```
if(gui.getEvent().getSource()==gui.getNext()&&gui.getpb().getValue()==100){
    gui.dispose();
    TrainingGui tgui = new TrainingGui();
}
```

Comment: *"switch between two frames"* 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Comment: I will check this out, thank you for commenting!